# Genotype result of double fertilization

Tags: genetics, homework, plant-physiology, plant-anatomy

[image]

So, clearly, the endosperm would be a fusion of the polar nuclei and one male gamete. Does this mean that each male gamete would have a T allele on it?

I can't seem to figure out a way to predict the allele distribution between the 2 polar nuclei since the flower has a Tt genotype.

Along the same lines, how can I predict what alleles the haploid egg would have? T or t? So, in that case, there would be a 50% chance of the embryo being TT and 50% chance of it being Tt (I didn't understand what the plus sign signifies).

The correct option is D, but I can't figure out how to get to that answer with absolute certainty.

Comment: The question is unclear to me. I understand we expect a triploid nucleus plus a diploid zygote (double fertilization) but I don't understand what `(TTT + TTt), TT` means.

Answer (score 1):

**IMO, the question is unclear**

The question is unclear to me. I understand we expect a triploid nucleus plus a diploid zygote (double fertilization) but I don't understand what `(TTT + TTt), TT` means.

- Which book did the question come from?
- Is there any preamble to this question?

**Double fertilization**

I am not so used to thinking about double fertilization in plants. In short, two pollens are involved. One fertilize a haploid gamete from the mother and the other fuse with two haploid gamete (polar nuclei) from the mother (triple fusion) resulting in a triploid "individual".

In my below answer, I am assuming that any two polar nuclei can fuse with the pollen. I am not sure this is true. If it is systematically polar nuclei resulting from the same meiosis II (that is they have the same parent cell after meiosis I), then t story is a little different.

**How I understand the question**

In my understanding, we are talking about a single locus with two alleles `T` and `t`. Both pollens are `T`. The mother is `Tt`.

**Answer**

There are two possible gametes from the female side `T` and `t`. Only one possible gamete from the male side `T`. Therefore, the diploid zygote is either

- $\frac{1}{2}$ `TT`
- $\frac{1}{2}$ `Tt`

, where the numbers indicate probabilities

Now, for the triploid nucleus resulting from the fertilisation of two polar nucleus from the mother and one pollen grain can be either

- $\frac{1}{4}$ `TTT`
- $\frac{1}{2}$ `TtT` or `tTT`
- $\frac{1}{4}$ `ttT`

Now, I have no idea how that matches to the possible answers as I don't understand the notation.